# How do you sample the call stack of a running process in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, command-line, profiling

Is there an existing program/utility that allows me to do what the macOS process sampler does? Ideally with a companion tool that allows me to aggregate the information into time spent within each call. I would like to take a 30-60s snapshot of what a process is doing while it's running.

Comment: pstack (https://linux.die.net/man/1/pstack) may print single stacks; full software and hardware sampling profiling in Linux currently can be implemented with `perf` tool (perf_events, http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html). `perf record -p $pid_of_process -g sleep 30` + `perf report` may work; also try `perf top -p  $pid_of_process`.

Comment: I had tried to install perf through linux-tools-common but it was not avaiable for my version of Linux (PopOS derived from Ubuntu). pstack output was not as informative as I'd have hoped.

Comment: Hello, do install perf for any kernel version of build it from any tar gz https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/. Debian & Ubuntu uses script at perf binary to select exact version from `uname -r` output: `/usr/lib/linux-tools/`uname -r`/perf`, just install any deb with perf binary and use it.